# How to keep session id after login in Laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel, session

I been using my session id to identify all the items that are added to a shopping cart temporary items table.

What I didn't know is that once the user login into the system the session id changes so I can't query the temporary items table anymore as there is no products containing the new session id value.

I am using file session driver and I was thinking to use db sessions but I think it will be exactly the same.

Any ideas on how to keep the session id after login?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using user's `session_id` you can store the cart items in a separate session key.

Like so -

```
Session::put('cart.items.0', $item_id);
```

Now you can access it as -

```
$cart = Session::get('cart');
```

Not exactly what you asked for, but to me this seems like a better way.

Comment: I appreciate you answer but doing it that way I will have to change the logic on my app. The other way I was thinking is via creating a random value, assigning it to a variable and store it in the session. Then check if the session value exist before anything else. The question is, once I get a new session ID after login will I lose other values I store in the session?